# How to overplot a grayscale with a binary mask in matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a 2-D magnetogram (equivalent to 2-d ndarray with dtype float values). I have a binary mask displaying some features. I'd like to display a hybrid image displaying the magnetogram in gray colormap and all the pixels which are 1 in the binary mask set to the color yellow. Let me know how can this be achieved in matplotlib or seaborn library.

TLDR: with an image and a mask, show image as black and white, just color the mask pixels yellow.

Regards,

Harsh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(nx), np.arange(ny))
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12), dpi=450) 
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
countours = ax1.contour(X, Y, mask, 0, colors='blue', linewidths=0.5) ##linewidth parameter had to be adjusted by eye estimation.
ax1.imshow(image, origin='lower', cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```